# Heroku Appears Different From Localhost

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a page of my rails app set up correctly on my `localhost`, but when I push it to `Heroku` everything goes quite wrong (with the exact same code, to the best of my knowledge).

Here is what shows up on my `localhost`:

[image: View from Localhost]

And here's what happens on `Heroku`:

[image: View from Heroku]

Here is the `html`/`erb` code for the page in question:

```
<div style="height: 80px"></div>

<div class="text-center">
  <h1 style="font-size: 10vh">Gift Helper</h1>
  <p>Select the age group for which you are being forced to shop.</p>
</div>

<div style="height: 50px" class="hidden-xs"></div>


<div class="text-center frame">
  <%= image_tag 'speedometer.jpg', style: "width: 100%; max-width: 700px", class: "vertical-align-in-div", alt: "Speedometer of Gifting.  Ooooh.  Aaaaah." %>
</div>

<div class="text-center frame" style="margin-top: -465px">
  <%= image_tag 'needle.png', id: "needle", style: "width: 100%; max-width: 290px", class: "vertical-align-in-div", alt: "The Needle of Wisdom." %>
</div>

<div class="frame" style="margin-top: -450px; width: 80%; margin-left: 10%">
  <%= link_to gifts_babies_path, id: "kids" do %>
    <div id="kids" class="stacking-boxes"></div>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to gifts_kids_path do %>
    <div id="teens" class="stacking-boxes"></div>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to gifts_teens_path do %>
    <div id="babies" class="stacking-boxes"></div>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to gifts_adults_path do %>
    <div id="adults" class="stacking-boxes"></div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<script>
  $('#babies').hover(
      function(){ $('#needle').addClass('animation-babies') },
      function(){ $('#needle').removeClass('animation-babies') }
  );
  $('#kids').hover(
      function(){ $('#needle').addClass('animation-kids') },
      function(){ $('#needle').removeClass('animation-kids') }
  );
  $('#teens').hover(
      function(){ $('#needle').addClass('animation-teens') },
      function(){ $('#needle').removeClass('animation-teens') }
  );
  $('#adults').hover(
      function(){ $('#needle').addClass('animation-adults') },
      function(){ $('#needle').removeClass('animation-adults') }
  );
</script>
```

And here is my `layout.html.erb` code.  I think this is relevant because it is the footer (amongst other things) that is being pulled up awkwardly on the `Heroku` version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Manly Art of BBQ</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= favicon_link_tag %>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo:400,900,100,700|Covered+By+Your+Grace|Josefin+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'Ckeditor.cdn_url' %>
</head>
<body>

<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><%= image_tag 'LogoTextWhite.png', style: "height: 50px; margin-top: -15px" %></a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to 'Man Rules', rules_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'BBQ', home_bbq_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Jokes', home_jokes_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Lifehacks', home_lifehacks_path %></li>
        <% if current_user %>
          <li><%= link_to user_path(current_user) do %>
            My Mancard <span style="background-color: red; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border-radius: 7px"><%= current_user.manpoints %></span>
          <% end %></li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to 'Log In', new_user_session_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- collapse -->
  </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
</div> <!-- custom-bootstrap-menu -->

<%= yield %>

<footer>
  <div class="row" style="height: 320px">
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
      <%= image_tag 'Logo.png', style: "margin-top: 40px !important; width: 225px; margin: 10px;" %>
    </div> <!-- logo column -->

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="hidden-xs" style="height: 60px"></div>
      <h2 class="text-center comment" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px; margin-bottom: 40px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; border-top: thick solid red; border-bottom: thick solid red !important">Helping Men Be Men</h2>
    </div> <!-- men be men column -->

    <div class="col-sm-4" style="height: 320px; position: relative">
      <%= image_tag "remote-control-menu.png", style: "position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0", class: "hidden-xs", usemap: "#image-map", alt: "Remote control menu.  Yes, you get to hold it." %>
      <%= image_tag "remote-control-menu.png", style: "position: absolute; display: block; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto", class: "visible-xs", usemap: "#image-map", alt: "Remote control menu.  Yes, you get to hold it." %>
    </div> <!-- remote column -->

    <map name="image-map">
      <% if current_user %>
        <area target="" alt="Sign Out" title="Sign Out" href="<%= url_for destroy_user_session_path %>" coords="177,85,121,54" shape="rect">
        <area target="" alt="My Mancard" title="My Mancard" href="<%= url_for user_path(current_user) %>" coords="64,148,24" shape="circle">
      <% else %>
        <area target="" alt="Sign In" title="Sign In" href="<%= url_for new_user_session_path %>" coords="121,51,177,87" shape="rect">
        <area target="" alt="My Mancard" title="My Mancard" href="<%= url_for new_user_session_path %>" coords="64,148,24" shape="circle">
      <% end %>
        <area target="" alt="BBQ" title="BBQ" href="<%= url_for home_bbq_path %>" coords="148,143,26" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Man Rules" title="Man Rules" href="<%= url_for rules_path %>" coords="234,144,27" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Lifehacks" title="Lifehacks" href="<%= url_for home_lifehacks_path %>" coords="66,230,26" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Jokes" title="Jokes" href="<%= url_for home_jokes_path %>" coords="148,223,27" shape="circle">
        <area target="" alt="Man Gear" title="Man Gear" href="#" coords="235,228,26" shape="circle">
    </map>
  </div> <!-- footer row -->
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, here is the relevant `SCSS`:

```
.frame {
    height: 450px; /*can be anything*/
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    position: relative;
}

.vertical-align-in-div {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.speedometer-label {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  color: red;
  font-family: $font-writing;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 7vh;
}

.stacking-boxes {
  height: 175px;
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  width: 49% !important;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Can anyone see where the error is here?  I can't figure out any answer that would make it different on `Heroku` than it is on my `localhost`.

Comment: I'd start by checking (in the chrome network inspector ) that all your assets are loading properly.

Comment: do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: @GuyDubrovski, only one console error to do with an asset that isn't used on that page, so nothing helpful...

Comment: @FrederickCheung, it appears all of the assets are loading properly according to the console, except the one (mentioned above) that doesn't affect this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing to `Heroku`'s help desk and got the following response:

> In your latest build log I notice the following line:
>
> Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally From the
>   docs
>   [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-locally)
>   you can see an explanation of what this means:
>
> If a `public/assets/manifest.yml` is detected in your app, Heroku will
>   assume you are handling asset compilation yourself and will not
>   attempt to compile your assets. Rails 4 uses a file called
>   `public/assets/manifest-<md5 hash>.json` instead. On both versions you
>   can generate this file by running `$ rake assets:precompile` locally
>   and checking the resultant files into Git.
>
> This means that if you ran `rake assets:precompile` locally, even just
>   once, and then checked in that manifest file that you would then need
>   to run assets:precompile and check the results into git before every
>   deploy. Whilst some of our customers like to do this to speed up their
>   deploys, it's quite a subtle change that can catch people out.
>
> I'd recommend removing the `public/assets/manifest.yml` file from your
>   git repo and re-deploying the app, so that asset compilation is done
>   automatically by Heroku again.

When I ran `rake assets:precompile` and then re-pushed my app to Heroku it solved the problem.